# Using CSS To Shade TD %

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following fiddle setup http://jsfiddle.net/Wap43/3/  I can't get the bars to shade.  It will work without the style="width:10%" inline.  Is there another way to get that completed in the html code?  Thanks

Update.  I got this to work:

```
echo '</td><td class="graph">
                                    <div class="bar green" style="width:'.$left.'%"></div>
                                    <div class="bar yellow" style="width:'.$temp2.'%"></div>
                                    <div class="bar red" style="width:'.$right.'%"></div>';

td.graph{
    width: 200px;
}
td.graph .bar {
    height:18px;
    float:left;
}
.green {
    background: green;
    width:10%;
}
.red {

    background: red;
    width:10%;
}
.yellow {
    background: orange;
    width:10%;
}
```

Comment: Works fine if you add a little content and fix your width issues: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Wap43/11/

Comment: And also close your open `div` elements.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'shade'. What is the result you want to achieve? BTW: you are missing 2! `</div>` in your fiddle.

Comment: I need them on the same line representing a bar graph, not separate lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update. I got this to work:

```
echo '</td><td class="graph">
                                    <div class="bar green" style="width:'.$left.'%"></div>
                                    <div class="bar yellow" style="width:'.$temp2.'%"></div>
                                    <div class="bar red" style="width:'.$right.'%"></div>';

td.graph{
    width: 200px;
}
td.graph .bar {
    height:18px;
    float:left;
}
.green {
    background: green;
    width:10%;
}
.red {

    background: red;
    width:10%;
}
.yellow {
    background: orange;
    width:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

DIVs expand to the width of their containers. Your table has no width, and is the container of your DIV. Therefore you DIV has no width either.

Give your table a width.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what you were shooting for, but here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Scorpionb/27Ev7/) with your code cleaned up, and (I think) working. You needed the table to have a width(or to be filled with data), to close your div's, and to add height to the red style. That might not be what you are looking for, but it seems like it fits the bill

Comment: As always, an upvote and accept is greatly appreciated that if this fits your needs :)